# How to create react element dynamically and append to parent element?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import { createElement, useRef, useState } from "react";

function CustomInput() {
  return (
    <>
      <input type="text" />
      <button>-</button>
    </>
  );
}

function App() {
  const ulRef = useRef<HTMLUListElement | null>(null);

  const handleAdd = () => {
    const newInp = createElement(CustomInput);

    ulRef.current?.append(newInp);
  };

  const handleRemove = () => {
      console.log(ulRef.current);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ul style={{ listStyle: "none" }} ref={ulRef}>
        <li>
          <CustomInput />
        </li>
      </ul>
      <button onClick={handleAdd}>Add another input</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I was trying to understand how to dynamically append new components/elements to some elements without using additional array or objects that has to store data. As a result I'm getting [object Object].

[Result as image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zD19j.png)

Comment: Not sure why you would want to append a react component like this? Technically React runs a virtual dom. So your component - CustomInput is not a dom element but a React component with its own extended properties. Why not instead just append an actual dom element? What is the reason for this implementation?

Comment: @SteveTomlin reason is simply learning. I was just curious and wanted to know is there any way to dynamically append React component with all the logic that it encapsulates such as props and handlers. Implementing separate logic to actual dom element seems repetative and cumbersome.

Comment: Yes I agree but this is not the React way. As Nick Parons describes below - it would get out of sync. Best instead to just include your React Custom component  without dynamically adding it. Just make it render if it receives props or not.

Answer (score 0):

React state should be used to drive how your UI renders. You shouldn't be performing DOM manipulation (eg: `append()`) to update it, as it can easily become out of sync with your state. There are a few ways you could use state to drive your UI logic, but one way is to use an array of objects. Each object within the array would contain some information about the custom input (eg: its unique `id`, value the input holds, etc.), when you want to add a new input, you will append a new object to the array by calling a state setter function, which will then rerender your UI that uses that array to render your `<CustomInput />` components for each element in your state.

Eg:

```js
const {useState} = React;

function CustomInput() {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <input type="text" />
      <button>-</button>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

function App() {
  // note: use a better id generator than Math.random()
  const [inputs, setInputs] = useState([{id: Math.random()}]);

  const handleAdd = () => {
     setInputs(currInputs => [...currInputs, {id: Math.random()}]);
  };

  const handleRemove = (id) => {
     // remove object with `id` from your `inputs` array
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ul style={{ listStyle: "none" }}>
        <li>
          {inputs.map(input => <CustomInput id={input.id} />)}
        </li>
      </ul>
      <button onClick={handleAdd}>Add another input</button>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.body).render(<App />);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

In the above example, the `inputs` array contains a set of object with a single property of `id`, however, you can add additional properties to these objects that further describe how your `CustomInput` may need to be rendered or props that might be needed for each input. If you find that you don't have any additional information to store on the objects, you can instead just push strings (representing ids) instead of objects into your array.

Comment: Maybe [crypto.randomUUID()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Crypto/randomUUID)

Comment: @jme11 Nice suggestion, I've also seen [uuidv4](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuidv4) used in the past, but `crypto.randomUUID()` seems like a better option these days

Comment: It's nice that you don't need a separate package.

Comment: @jme11 yes definitely!

Comment: Thank you I do actually use it this way in actual commercial projects. Just wanted to know if there any other ways to do such thing.